# Django: How To Remove Invalid Dates From DateField

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

My form allows users to input invalid dates like 31 of febuary, is there a way to exclude certain dates in a range?

models:

```
release_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

froms:

```
YEARS = [x for x in range(1900,2030)]

class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    release_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_date'}, years=YEARS, empty_label="---"), required=False)
```

views:

```
def newPost(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Post(author=request.user)
        form = NewPost(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myposts')
    else:
        form = NewPost()

    return render(request, 'create/new_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You can check in your view if the date is in range, and if it is not do not save it into the DB.

Comment: Can you *save* the 31st of february? Normally the form, or at least the database should reject this.

Comment: Oh, The form does reject it. but it is still an option in the date picker which is odd

Comment: `form.is_valid()` checks if the date is inside the `YEARS` list so you don't have to check anything.

Comment: @HumzaDin: I think the `SelectDateWidget` is probably not the best option. There are some packages like [**`django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/) that provide more convenient widgets. So perhaps it is worth to look around, or implement a widget yourself.